# Sonar 5.6.1 - "new issues" were created but there was no new commit or changes on jenkins/sonar configuration

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have some projects with the same Gate Profile and Gate Quality and Leak Period on Sonar, and same "parent projects" on Jenkins.
Jenkins is configured to build the projects every day as 1:00 AM and when there is a commit.

Recently, sonar reportered "new issues" on three of those projects, but on those three projects there was no commit between the builds (ie. the last build with success and the next build, that reported the "new issues", used the same changeset).

And the "new issues" did not show up in the same day (what would be expected if we changed some global configuration or made some update). For one project the new issues appeared 2017-02-11 01:20 for the second on 2017-02-13 01:00 and for the third on 2017-02-14 01:17.

There was no recently change on the configuration in jenkins or sonar (global or project specific), in special no new rule were added.
All "new issues" are from the same rule "Null pointers should not be dereferenced" (from squid) which was already part of the Quality Profile used before the "new issues".

I even compared the console output of the builds but there was no relevant difference  on the sonar outputs (except for the timestamps and the "fail" in the and because there were "new issues").

How can I discovered what happended?

And is there a way to change the "creation date" of the issues?
(for now we will not fix that "new issues", becuse they are actually old issues - from old code - and we don't want to configure a specific Leak Period for those three projects, and we dont want to mark those issues as resolved...)

Comment: Do you confirm that a nightly analysis _did_ run on all 3 projects all 3 nights?

Comment: yes. They run 2017-02-10,  2017-02-10,  2017-02-12,  2017-02-14

Comment: Did you _upgrade_ the relevant code analyzers in that period?

Comment: No, the last change we made was on 2017-02-09 at the morning. Just after that we run all builds and all of them were successful. The next nightly on ~ 2017-02-10 1:00 of all projects were successful tpp. And all build from those three projects were using the same changeset since 2017-02-09.

Comment: Does your Jenkins job do a full rebuild each time?

Comment: have you changed the quality profiles?

Comment: 1-  full rebuild.
2 - no changes were made on quality profiles (in special there are "old issues" of the same rule of the "new issues")

Comment: I think I discovered what happened... (at least I was able to repeat the creation of a "new issue" without new commits or changes on sonar/jenkins...)
it seems like an user had marked those issues as "Resolve as Fixed".
When i've done that today (just to test), the next build was a success (no "new issue"), but the following build generate a "new issue" (exactly the one that I had marked as "Resolve as Fixed").

The strange thing here is: why do the build just after the "Resolve as Fixed" do not recreated the Issue (just the second build made that)?

Comment: And, is there a way to know that a fixed issue was explicity marked as "Resolve as Fixed", and who do that?
The tooltip seems the same, if the issue was acctualy fixed (the code was changed) or if the issue is just marked as "Resolve as Fixed" :(
February 14, 2017 2:28 PM  Created by <user>
February 14, 2017 3:06 PM  Resolution changed to FIXED
Status changed to CLOSED (was OPEN)